# replace a number in a for loop in a link address in a bash file

Tags: bash, for-loop, replace

[I searched a lot about this but didn't find any solution.] 
I have some link addresses and they are the same except in one part, they are like the following: 
http://download.com/das.fsdsa.ss01.ffsa 
http://download.com/das.fsdsa.ss02.ffsa 
http://download.com/das.fsdsa.ss03.ffsa 
as you can see just the numbers are changing. 
I want to write a bash file that in a for loop change the number and download it and then increase that specific number and then do it again. 
Therefore, I will not have to copy and paste the links all the time. 
I am not familiar with bash programming, to be honest.
if you be kind enough and guide me about replacing the numbers at least, I will appreciate that. 

 Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your input, I mean the (list of) URL(s): in a file, or in a variable?

Comment: there is no list, I want to give one link and then it will replace the number and go ahead and download.

Comment: From which number do you want to start, and at which number will you stop?

Comment: from 01 to 24. thanks

Comment: As an introduction to the topic: `for i in {01..24}; do echo "${i}"; done`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one liner, without bash and without for-loop:

```
curl http://download.com/das.fsdsa.ss[01-24].ffsa --output das.fsdsa.ss\#1.ffsa
```

Or, if you prefer a bash loop:

```
for i in {01..24} ; do
  curl http://download.com/das.fsdsa.ss$i.ffsa --output das.fsda.ss$i.ffsa
done
```

Comment: Which one? The first or the second one?

Comment: the second one I used in bash file, with axel -n 10